# Why the value is not moved with Option unwrap?

Tags: rust, move

New to rust here and trying to learn. Consider the following piece of code:

```
let x = Some("air");
println!("{}", x.unwrap());
println!("{}", x.unwrap());
```

Why does this work? Because the `unwrap` method has the following signature `pub fn unwrap(self) -> T`, so it should move `self` into the method, which means after the first call of `x.unwrap`, I shouldn't be able to access `x` anymore. However this still works? Can someone explain what misunderstanding I am taking here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are confusing `&str` with `String`, which rather is not `Copy`.

```rust
fn main() {
    // This will work fine.
    let x = Some("data");
    println!("{:?}", x.unwrap());
    println!("{:?}", x.unwrap());

    // however, this will generate an error since value will be moved.
    let x = Some("data".to_string());
    println!("{:?}", x.unwrap());
    println!("{:?}", x.unwrap());
}
```

Comment: Good answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Just figured out, `x` in OP is not moved because `Option<&str>` implements the `Copy` trait. On the other hand if the inner type in the option is a more complex type for instance a `struct`, this wouldn't work:

```
struct Node<T> { elem: T }

let y = Some(Node { elem: 3});

println!("{}", y.unwrap().elem);
println!("{}", y.unwrap().elem);
```

will give the following error:

> ```
> Line 33, Char 24: use of moved value: `y` (solution.rs)
>    |
> 32 |         println!("{}", y.unwrap().elem);
>    |                        - value moved here
> 33 |         println!("{}", y.unwrap().elem);
>    |                        ^ value used here after move
>    |
> ```

Comment: `x` is `Option<&str>`, not `Option<String>`. `Option<String>` doesn't implement `Copy`.

Comment: @SCappella Thanks for the clarification. Updated!

Answer (score -2):

The `unwrap()` method is used to remove the parent element from the selected element and not the element itself.

Lets say `Y` is parent for 'X' and 'Z' is parent of 'Y' then when you say `x.unwrap()` X's parent 'Y' is removed and 'Z' becomes the parent of 'X' and now when you say `x.unwrap()` again then 'Z' is removed.

Comment: What is the "parent element" in this case?